# Scala recursive API calls to get all the results

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming

I'm pretty new to Scala, and what I'm trying to achieve is to make enough calls to an API with different offset until I get all the results.

Here's a simplified version of what I have, and I was wondering if there is a more idiomatic Scala way to do it. (The code sample might not be 100% accurate, it's just something I put up as an example)

```
def getProducts(
                 limit: Int = 50,
                 offset: Int = 0,
                 otherProducts: Seq[Product] = Seq()): Future[Seq[Product]] = {

  val eventualResponse: Future[ApiResponse] = apiService.getProducts(limit, offset)

  val results: Future[Seq[Product]] = eventualResponse.flatMap { response =>

    if (response.isComplete) {
      logger.info("Got every product!")
      Future.successful(response.products ++ otherProducts)
    } else {
      logger.info("Need to fetch more data...")

      val newOffset = offset + limit
      getProducts(limit, newOffset, otherProducts ++ response.products)
    }
  }

  results
}
```

Passing the `otherProducts` parameter just doesn't feel right :P

Thanks in advance for any suggestions :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you've exposed the tail recursion implementation, which is a bit like implementation detail in functional programming.

As for me, I typically wrap such functions into an external call without accumulator parameter (`otherProducts`):

```
def getProducts(limit: Int = 50, offset: Int = 0): Future[Seq[Product]] = {
   def loop(limit: Int = 50,
             offset: Int = 0,
             acc: Seq[Product] = Seq()): Future[Seq[Product]] = ... your code with tail recursion...

   loop(limit, offset)
}
```

But it is just a matter of taste, and of course it is valid if `otherProducts` is just a fancy name for tailrec accumulator.